# What does ${!} and ${!!} mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would appreciate if someone would answer me, rather than just deleting obsessively saying this that and the other and not actually answer.

I have a command

```
#/bin/sh 
while :; \
do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; \
```

Does $$ refer to the second process, i.e. SLEEP?
What would `${!}` mean? I really don't know the syntax (I mean I understand the processes but I cannot find exactly why it has two $$ signs, and what the {!} is for.

If someone could enlighten me before deleting my question I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: I get `-bash: wait: '67469{!}': not a pid or valid job spec` when I try this (which kind of makes sense because `$$` expands to the PID of `sleep` but `67469{!}` isn't a PID. Does the code work for you?

Comment: The subject mentions `${!!}` but the code has `$${1}`. Which is it? `wait $${!}` would make sense in a Makefile, not in a sh script

Comment: Note that the shebang syntax is `#! /bin/sh -`. Why the bash tag if that's meant to be sh code?

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says:

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed as an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see Job Control Builtins).

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters

The `$${!}` as well as `${!!}` are mistakes.

If you run the script as posted, you should have an error:

```
./tst.sh: line 3: wait: `1234{!}': not a pid or valid job spec
```

Here 1234 is a pid of the shell itself, expanded from `$$`. And `{!}` is just a string constant.

The `${!!}` is syntactically correct, but tries to do an indirect expansion of variable `!` and since such variable cannot really exist - the error is: `${!!}: bad substitution`

The indirection is explained here:
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

**If you actually have that code (with `$${!}`)** and it actually works. Then this is, most likely not a shell script, but an embedding of a shell script into some other language. The one which also uses `$` to mark a variable. Most of such languages uses duplication of the dollar sign as escape, so `$$anything` become just a `$anything` after the host language done with a string which contains a shell script.

Comment: Re. `${!!}`, what's amusing is that e.g. `${!1}`, `${!0}`, and `${!@}` work, even though one refers to a positional parameter, and the other two refer to special parameters, which is what `$!` (or `!`) also is.